# All my checkboxes are now red

Tags: 20.04, colors

I have this strange problem in that all application checkboxes have turned red color.

Below is an example the Ubuntu Software dialog:

[image]

This started a week or so ago, so may be related to a recent update.
Version is Ubuntu 20.04.3

I have absolutely no idea how or why or where to even begin looking for what is causing this (compounded by being a linux noob as well).

If anyone knows of anything I can try to change the colors of the boxes back to normal that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: oh wow!  Now I feel like a real idiot as that was so simple!  Thanks for the answer - I switched to yaru-light then back to yaru-dark and the problem is gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Yaru Dark GTK theme. The theme is producing this unwanted behaviour, follow these steps to fix it:

1. First install gnome tweaks by running:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Launch the applications using:

   ```
   $ gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Navigate to *Appearance* → *Icon*
4. Select the Yaru light theme.

That's it! 
Good Luck!